# Vue methods method doesn't return anything with if statement

Tags: vuejs2

I am using if statement inside a function inside `methods` to check telephone number. Now I can do `console.log` to the value and it is actually showing back the value, but when I write if statement to test it it doesn't return or print anything.

```vue
methods: {
  phoneState () {
    let phonetest = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4,})$/;
    console.log( phonetest.test(this.phone_number) )

    if (phonetest.test(this.phone_number) == false) {
      phonenumberchecking = false
      console.log('test false')
    } else {
      phonenumberchecking = null
      console.log('test null')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because of the double `is equals to` sign. Try using `===` instead of `==`

Visit https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a for more information

```
methods: {
phoneState () {

              let phonetest = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4,})$/;
              console.log( phonetest.test(this.phone_number) )

              if( phonetest.test(this.phone_number) === false ){
                  phonenumberchecking = false
                  console.log('test false')
              }else{
                phonenumberchecking = null
                console.log('test null')
              }
    }
}
```